# How do I use an old windows hard-drive like a backup drive?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

I recently bought a new SSD. I set it up, and now my old hard drive is just laying around. It'd be nice if I could put files on it (word files, etc... things that don't take power to run) so I could clear up space on my (small 256GB) SSD.

I plugged it in like a normal hard drive and my explorer looks like this:

[image]

I don't see it anywhere. I'm fine with clearing/formatting the old drive I just want to know what to do so I can access it.

This is an internal hard drive (I *believe* SATA 3). I tried plugging it in like a normal internal hard drive and it just didn't show up.

**Here are some pictures. I edited them in MSPaint so sorry if that irks you.**

[image]

This is what it looks like when it's setup correctly. the blue cord used to be plugged into where the arrow is. Also (if you noticed), there's blue tape there because my case isn't small enough to securely hold the SSD in place. If that's a bad idea and I should do something else please tell me (without the tape it's dangled from the cords connecting it)

---

[image]

This is the `The double connection cord` I mentioned in the comments. It's plugged into both harddrives, as you can see in the above image.

---

[image]

This is the blue cord that's plugged into the SSD. I put an arrow where it is plugged in normally.

---

I don't see it in disc management:

[image]

Comment: You might need to install additional drivers for your motherboard. I'd also check the BIOS to see if its being detected there. If not, chances are you might have plugged it incorrectly.

Comment: @happy_soil The double connection cord was built-in to my motherboard. Wouldn't the driver always support two connections?

Comment: *"The double connection cord ..."* -- What cables are you referring to? *"I believe SATA 3"* -- The SATA capabilities should be on the label of the HDD.  There should no reason to guess.  No offense intended, but you don't come across as HW savvy (although you did successfully install your new SSD).  Please explain in detail the connections of the new SSD and old HDD.  You did connect the HDD *before* you booted the PC, right?

Comment: I'm not hardware savvy at all, I'm much better with software. I am only guessing that it was SATA because that's what it says on the box, I actually plugged in two cords. And yes, I did.

Comment: You have applied power  (yellow/black/red/orange) to both the SSD and HD. You did not connect a SATA cable to the HD. Thus, the computer does not see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first picture only shows a SATA cable connected to your SSD.  The SATA cable is the blue one.  You'll need to connect an appropriate SATA cable to the HDD.  Hopefully, your motherboard has an appropriate a second SATA connector to support the HDD.  When both drives are connected by SATA cables to the motherboard, you should be able to access both drives.

There may be other issues, like drivers or BIOS settings, that need to be addressed as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your old disk might not be formatted or partitioned correctly, so it's not showing up in explorer. However, you should be able to find it in the disk manager.

To do this, right click "My Computer" then click "manage", then go down to "Disk Management". This should list the disks attached to your system. From there you should be able to partition and format the drive to be useable. If the disk does not show up in here, check the connection again - windows does not recognize your drive.

Comment: Be aware that formatting your drive will erase all the data on it.  Make sure you don't have anything on it before  you format it.

Comment: *"Your old disk might not be formatted or partitioned correctly"*  -- If this "old" drive was used to boot Win8, how could it now be formatted or partitioned incorrectly?

Comment: I don't see my disc there. [This](http://puu.sh/4Lc6o.png) is all I See.